# All documents in the collection magically disappeared. Can i find out what happened?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I cloned 2 of my collections from localhost to a remote location on MongoLab platform yesterday. I was trying to debug my (MEAN stack) application (with WebStorm IDE) and i realized one of those collections have no data in it. Well, there were 7800 documents this morning...

I am pretty much the only one who works on the database and especially with this collection. I didn't run any query to remove all of the documents from this collection. In mongolab's website there is a button says 'delete all documents from collection'. I am pretty sure I didn't hit that button. I asked my team mates; no one even opened that web page today.

Assuming that my team is telling the truth and I didn't remove everything and have a black out...

Is there a way to find out what happened? 
And, is there a way to keep a query history (like unix command-line history) for mongo database that runs on a remote server? And if yes, how?

So, I am just curious about what happened. Also note that I don't have any DBA responsibilities or experience in that field.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB replica sets have a special collection called oplog. This collection stores all write operations for all databases in that replica set.

Here are instructions on how to access oplog in Mongolab:
[Accessing the MongoDB oplog](http://docs.mlab.com/oplog/)

Here is a query that will find all delete operations:

```
use local
db.oplog.rs.find({"op": "d", "ns" : "db_name.collection_name"})
```